# ASUS UX533F temperature too high and fan off on Ubuntu 19.04

Tags: asus, temperature, nvidia-geforce

Using this **[boot workaround](https://askubuntu.com/a/1148600/665307)**, I have been able to install Ubuntu 19.04 on my recently acquired ASUS UX533FN:

- ASUS BIOS version 202 (already up-to-date)
- **NVidia GeForce MX150** with NVidia proprietary driver **418** installed
- Linux version 5.0.0-16-generic
- no Intel microcode update for the moment (`dis_ucode_ldr` as linux boot param)

Audio is working! For comparison, I haven't been able to have it working on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.

Now my problem is **the CPU temperature is very high!** around 70-80°C  without doing anything special that'd claim much CPU power - just writing these lines for example... **and the fan doesn't run at all**.

---

I have found the following **workaround**:

```
sudo prime-select query
```

If this command returns `nvidia`, then run:

```
sudo prime-select intel
```

then log off.

Result:
When you log back on, check the CPU temperature decreases and reach reasonable values (between 40°C and 50°C for example, depending on the room temperature), and you should hear the fan running when needed.

But this is only a workaround with which the NVIDIA GPU is not used at all...

---

### Questions

**How can I have the NVIDIA graphics card and the fan operational, without the CPU temperature going high?**

**Maybe I should stick with the Intel graphics only?** I didn't ask for an NVidia card in the first place... I didn't realize this laptop had an NVidia card when I bought it.

Comment: Current BIOS? What version Nvidia? Is your card supported in Nvidia 430? Why no Intel microcode updates?

Comment: No Intel microcode update is the only way to boot at the moment. See:  https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1829620

Comment: BIOS 202 actually

Comment: NVidia driver, I'll check and let you know (the version installed automatically today when installing Ubuntu 19.04).

Comment: I have tried upgrading the ASUS BIOS to version 300, the flash utility (in the ASUS system setup) saw it on the USB key but rejected it.

Comment: See also:  https://github.com/intel/Intel-Linux-Processor-Microcode-Data-Files/issues/1

Comment: Either you have a bad BIOS 300 download, or there's a problem with the flash key, or it's in the wrong format.

Comment: Here's the only version I can find (maybe not exactly the same UX533F model?): https://www.asus.com/us/Laptops/ASUS-Zenbook-15-UX533FD/HelpDesk_BIOS/

Comment: I'll search and try again with other USB configs (partition, filesystem, ...)

Comment: You can flash from HDD/SSD, it doesn't have to be a USB flash driver. See https://www.asus.com/us/support/FAQ/1008859

Comment: NVidia driver version is 418 (installed automatically today when installing Ubuntu 19.04)

Comment: ASUSTeK Easy Flash Utility says "Selected file is not a proper BIOS !"...

Comment: Re: the BIOS did you select the .zip file, or the .300 file? Nvidia's latest is 430, I believe, and if it supports your card, you may wish to install it. I've added an answer about using `thermald` to help cool your machine... but I'd do the BIOS and Nvidia first.

Comment: I tried the Zip file, the .300 file. A few days ago I tried the NVidia 430 (on Ubuntu 18.04, though) and had to fallback to 418 (I don't remember why). Thanks for the answer about thermald. I won't try it right now and concentrate on my **network connection issue**: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1148630/asus-ux533f-ethernet-on-usb-not-working

Comment: I found out the BIOS is already up-to-date.
Here's the correct link to the BIOS file for ASUS UX533FN:
https://www.asus.com/za/Laptops/ASUS-Zenbook-15-UX533FN/HelpDesk_BIOS/

Comment: Ah... we've got an updated model number... :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To date, the best answer is to use the following **workaround**:

---

```
sudo prime-select intel
```

then log off.

---

After that, I have no more temperature issue with my laptop, and the fan does work when needed.

*The drawback is that the NVidia GPU is simply not used at all, but it's fine for me.
If I'd known this laptop model had an NVidia card when I bought it, I'd have selected the same model but without an NVidia card.*

Answer (score 0):

If you can't figure a way to cool down your machine with BIOS updates, etc., or Nvidia updates, you might install `thermald`. It comes with a default .xml configuration file that may require some tweaking to get it customized for your hardware, and for setting the desired temperature.

- sudo apt-get update
- sudo apt-get install thermald

`Thermald` was buggy in early versions of 16.04. Update to 16.04.2 and it should be ok.

`Thermald` comes with a default configuration file at `/etc/thermald/thermal-conf.xml` that will control most computers, but may need to be customized for some computers. See `man thermal-conf.xml` for some details and examples. Once one has modified the configuration file, stop `thermald` and restart it:

```
sudo service thermald restart
```

After installing thermald, I'd stop the `thermald` process, and run it manually as `sudo thermald --no-daemon` to watch its actions in real time. This real time info can be used to create your own customized thermal-conf.xml file. See `man thermald` for more information.

```
sudo service thermald stop
sudo thermald --no-daemon --loglevel=debug
```

You can search for `thermald` here on Ask Ubuntu to see what previous answers there are.

A good starter reference is at https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/PowerManagement/ThermalIssues

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because your NVIDIA is electronically on and drain your battery

To turn off your secondary GPU manually, first find your GPU PCI adress :

```
lspci | grep "NVIDIA"

$ lspci | grep "NVIDIA"
02:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GP107M [GeForce GTX 1050 Mobile] (rev a1)
```

For my case my PCI adress is 02:00.0

Now we can check if your secondary GPU is draining your battery, run :

```
cat /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000\:**[PCI_ADRESS]**/power/control
```

If output is "on" then your secondary GPU is forced on and drain your battery
To turn it off run :

```
sudo sh -c 'echo auto > /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000\:[PCI_ADRESS]/power/control'
```

Comment: Maybe your suggestion is for my other post ? https://askubuntu.com/q/1241937/665307