# ASUS UX533F ethernet on USB not working?

Tags: ethernet, hdmi, asus, usb-c

On my ASUS UX533FN (laptop), I'm having problems with an USB-to-ethernet dockstation, model C31FLATDOCKPDV2 from i-tec.
This device also provides an additional HDMI port via DisplayPort over USB-C.

The problem is that it is not detected...well not always. 1 hour ago it was working fine, I disconnected it from the USB-C port and reconnected it several times without success.

After a warm-reboot or a cold-reboot...same problem.

Here are the kernel logs when I plug the dock station:

```
Bus 001 Device 021: ID 046d:c534 Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 001 Device 020: ID 05e3:0610 Genesys Logic, Inc. 4-port hub
Bus 001 Device 018: ID 05e3:0610 Genesys Logic, Inc. 4-port hub
```

Any suggestion how I could solve this issue?

The same dock station causes me absolutely no worries with another ASUS laptop, model UX430.

Comment: Check your BIOS for the equivalent of "Legacy" mode for USB ports... only for USB-C ports.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, there is no such thing in this particular ("BIOS") system setup menu, only the choice to completely disable the use of external USB devices.

Comment: I guess I should try to capture the `lsmod`, `lspci`, `lshw`, and `dmesg` logs when it works (if it ever happens again), and the same logs when it doesn't work, in order to compare both logs...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was in fact caused by a hardware issue with the I-Tec dock-station itself (model C31FLATDOCKPDV2), so not an Ubuntu issue.

I was putting the dock-station upside down on the table, in order to have its USB cable on the right side of my ASUS UX533FN (USB-C port on the right), whereas the dock-station was upside up for use with my ASUS UX430 (USB-C port on the left).

After I suspected this to be the cause of the issue, I turned the dock-station back to the standard upside up position. Since then, I never had the issue anymore! Ethernet and HDMI (DisplayPort) over USB-C are working fine.

For a "normal" electronic device, turning it upside down shouldn't be a problem...so I assume there is a hardware quality issue with my I-Tec dock-station. I suspect a soldering defect such as described [here](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-guide-excellent-soldering/common-problems) or something of the kind.