# ASUS UX533F temperature too high and fan off on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Tags: asus, overheating, fan, nvidia-geforce

After installing Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, my laptop's temperature goes fairly high without intensive CPU activity. The fan(s) remain **off** under heavy CPU load and the temperature goes very high.

I don't suspect a material failure since I didn't have [such overheating issues anymore with my previous Ubuntu (19.04)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1148604/asus-ux533f-temperature-too-high-and-fan-off-on-ubuntu-19-04).

---

**EDIT:** at the moment, after random attempts such as Uninstall/Reinstall the NVidia propietary driver, Downgrade/Upgrade the Linux kernel... The only issue left is `sensors` still sees the fan off (0 RPM) though I can hear it. No more overheating with my ASUS UX533F, hurray! but I don't know why so the problem might as well reappear some day...

---

**Config**

- ASUS UX533FN
- BIOS version 304 (up-to-date)
- Kernel: 5.4.0-31-generic (same issue with 5.4.0-29)
- NVIDIA GeForce MX150 (with latest NVIDIA driver)

**Low CPU load**

Without running anything special, I get the following figures with `sensors` command:

```
...
pch_cannonlake-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +49.0°C  

BAT0-acpi-0
Adapter: ACPI interface
in0:          15.60 V  

asus-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
cpu_fan:        0 RPM

coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Package id 0:  +50.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 0:        +49.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 1:        +48.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 2:        +48.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 3:        +50.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)

acpitz-acpi-0
Adapter: ACPI interface
temp1:        +49.0°C  (crit = +103.0°C)
```

These figures are a too high in my opinion for low CPU load with a room temperature of 20°C.

But here come's worse:

**Heavy CPU load**

When the CPU is under load, for instance when running `sysbench cpu run` in loop, the temperature increases to 90°C, and no fan is triggered!

To get a repeatable CPU load test, I run

```
while true; do echo "One more time..." && sysbench cpu run; done
```

Here are the figures I get in this case (from `sensors` command):

```
...
pch_cannonlake-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +65.0°C  

BAT0-acpi-0
Adapter: ACPI interface
in0:          15.60 V  

asus-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
cpu_fan:        0 RPM

coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Package id 0:  +88.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 0:        +88.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 1:        +70.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 2:        +72.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 3:        +72.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)

acpitz-acpi-0
Adapter: ACPI interface
temp1:        +86.0°C  (crit = +103.0°C)
```

Note 1: The temperature in the room for this test is 20°C.

Note 2: I reported [almost the same issue one year ago with Ubuntu 19.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1148604/asus-ux533f-temperature-too-high-and-fan-off-on-ubuntu-19-04).

**What I already tried**

- installing the latest NVIDIA driver, including selecting `intel` with `prime-select` ameliorated the situation but didn't tackle the issue
- running `sensors-detect` (YES to all questions) resulted in `coretemp` to be added to `/etc/modules`
- running `pwmconfig` didn't work:

```
/usr/sbin/pwmconfig: There are no pwm-capable sensor modules installed
```

How would **you** tackle this overheating issue?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Did you try to enable "Fan always on" in BIOS? I think the fan speed doesn't depend on the OS you're using because the BIOS controls it. You should try another OS (such as Windows) to see if it is same as in Ubuntu. In another OS, try to overload your CPU and/or GPU.

Comment: Thanks. I don't have a "fan always ON" option in the BIOS. What do you mean "_overload_ your CPU or GPU"?

Comment: Do a stresstest in another OS such as Windows to check if Ubuntu causes it.

Comment: Thanks but I don't have a live-USB MS-Windows so I can't do that.

Comment: If you didn't have issues in earlier releases of Ubuntu, you can try it for example in Ubuntu 19.10. Just find an application that will do the stresstest.

Comment: I had a similar issue with Ubuntu 19.04: https://askubuntu.com/q/1148604/665307

Comment: I more or less remember the operations I performed with my laptop Ubuntu 20.04 recently, I think it might be: Uninstall and purge NVidia proprietary driver, (re-)install the NVidia proprietary driver, Downgrade/Upgrade the Linux kernel... which should make no difference. But the thing is I don't have any "overheating and fan off" problem at the moment. The only issue I have now is a minor issue: `sensors` reports 0 RPM though the fan is working.

Answer (score 0):

Your case is interresting and looks like mine

**Config**

- Asus UX480FD
- Intel UHD 610 x NVIDIA GTX 1050 Max-Q

**About fans**

My fans don't seems to work proprely, my computer have very high temps quickly and won't cool down

```
$ sensors
asus-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
cpu_fan:        0 RPM
```

Did you check this GitHub ? I tried for my Asus but it doesn't work, I'm still working on it
https://github.com/dominiksalvet/asus-fan-control

There is maybe a reason why your fans doesn't trun on when your computer is hot
Fans have multiples speed levels, and maybe your first level start at 52° (like me)

More info here : https://github.com/dominiksalvet/asus-fan-control#custom-temperatures

I'll keep you informed if I find more info about it

Comment: Thanks. At the time of this writing, the only current issue I have is the fan is not seen as running by `sensors` though I can hear it's running. I have no more temperature issue at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
After updating the BIOS it solved.
download link:
https://www.asus.com/Laptops/ASUS-ZenBook-15-UX533FN/HelpDesk_BIOS/

Comment: Thanks @ashkan_sl I'll check (as soon as I'm less busy) and come back to you... but my BIOS is up-to-date, no?

Comment: yes you have the newest version.

Comment: I had ubuntu alongside win10.
When i power on the laptop and go to ubunut directly, fans don't work.
But when at first go to windows and then restart it and then go to ubuntu they work properly.

Comment: In addition sensors still show 0 rpm for cpu fan.
But the left fan work properly.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing that very same problem with my ASUS ZenBook 15 UX533FTC-A8304T where I'm dual bootinf Windows 10 and Ubuntu. Starting Ubuntu, temperature shoots up to 50+°C when laptop is left on idle and up to 60+° when using chrome with just 3 tabs on.

The solution that worked for me was to cut off power (I'm assuming that's what it meant) to the NVIDIA gpu. I'm not gaming or doing any graphic intensive activities on the Ubuntu so this is fine for me. But if there's a reason that someone knows why this works or has to be done, please share.
Now the temperature sits around 39°C when left on idle with no programs running and 43° with chrome and spotify open.
Battery life expectancy has also doubled.

I realized the command the solution provided needs to be manually run on every boot. So, you need to write a bash script file with the command and include it on the root cron job scheduled with @reboot. So, you can add a line at the end of your root crontab file like so.
`@reboot /path/to/script.sh`

Solution is based on: https://askubuntu.com/a/1245236/1097045

1. Get the PCI address of the NVIDIA GPU; it's `02:00.0` in this case.

```
$ lspci | grep "NVIDIA"

02:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GP107M [GeForce GTX 1050 Mobile] (rev a1)
```

2. Create a bash script file to include the following command and replace the PCI address if needed (preceded with a colon).

```
#!/bin/bash

echo auto > /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000\:02:00.0/power/control
```

3. Add the following line to `sudo crontab -e`
   `@reboot /path/to/script.sh`

Comment: What's the content of your `script.sh`?

Comment: I've updated my response.

Comment: On my laptop (issue not present for two weeks) `cat /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000\:02\:00.0/power/control` returns `auto` as well. Good to know in case I have the issue again in the future.

Comment: Did you try `sudo prime-select intel` ?

Comment: Yes I did that too.

Comment: So we probably had the same issue. On my laptop it mysteriously disappeared, and on yours you are using this workaround. Unfortunately I can't test it since I don't have the issue anymore.